# Dont auto hide the actionbar when typing text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity with an action bar and a text box in the activity. When i type "a lot of" text in to the textbox the action bar automatically scrolls out of the window. How can i disable this?

I already tried `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in ur activity tag inside manifest

**android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"**